# Updating Values of JSONB with the help of current value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update

I have a database having columns id and profile fields where profile fields is of the type jsonb

| id | profile_fields |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | {"1":"Chess" , "2":"08-02-2001"} |
| 102 | {"1":"Hockey" , "2":"1996-06-09"} |

In profile fields the key 2 stands for Date of Birth .

Unfortunately many fields have values in format yyyy/mm/dd .

I would like to change all the Date of birth values in dd/mm/yyyy format.

The Expected results is like this

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | {"1":"Chess" , "2":"08-02-2001"} |
| 102 | {"1":"Hockey" , "2":"09-06-1996"} |

I tried the update the update statement but i am stuck how can i apply in multiple values ? What will go inside where statement. And how to access the key 2 profile_fields->"2" is not in Update statement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a `regexp_replace` to mutate the datetime format when invalid ones are matched:

```sql
update tbl t set profile_fields = (select jsonb_object_agg(t1.key, regexp_replace(
     case when regexp_match(t1.value::text, '\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2}') is null 
         then t1.value::text 
         else regexp_replace(t1.value::text, '(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})', '\3-\2-\1') end, '"', '', 'g')) 
   from jsonb_each(t.profile_fields) t1)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h_jlVX_q).

Comment: I want to update the existing value some thing like `UPDATE users SET users.profile_fields->>"2"`

Comment: @ChessKnowledge Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is using the `||` operator and `regexp_replace` to reshape the date format.

```sql
update the_table
set profile_fields = profile_fields || jsonb_build_object
 ('2', regexp_replace(profile_fields->>'2','(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)','\3-\2-\1'))
where profile_fields->>'2' ~ '\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d';
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kmHsX8Zu5mAvCzb1Q7mqX5/0)
Please note that this approach - using the `||` operator - only works for the first-level keys or for "flat" JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much Stefanov.sm

Comment: Can you please explain how does the `~` operator work in the where clause ? I Googled it but only find ~ of numbers.

Comment: This is the regular expression match operator In Postgresql. [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).